# PipeReader Advance for number of bytes

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, system.io.pipelines

How to advance `PipeReader` exact number of bytes? (I'm not interested in skipped data)

`AdvanceTo` overloads only expects `SequencePosition` which is not user constructible.